# What are the methods to improve headlights of a car?

Tags: electrical, toyota, headlight, wiring, carina

I'd like to improve the headlight illumination on my Toyota Carina AT 150. It is equipped with square type 55W lamps, but it's difficult to drive in the city or rainy/misty conditions. What are my options to improve the lighting performance? HIDs?

If I modify my lights, will the existing battery and alternator be able to bear this additional load?

Can I replace existing 55W bulbs with 100W bulbs?

Comment: What year of Carina is this? You must be talking about the 86 you mentioned in your previous post.

Comment: One thing that can greatly affect the amount of useful light coming from your headlamps is the clarity of the plastic/acrylic lens cover (the part of the headlight that you can touch from outside the car). On many cars, the lens cover loses clarity and becomes gradually more hazy and "milky" over time, reducing the effective light output of the lamps. Are your lens covers clear and in good condition?

Comment: @RSW ... If what I've seen is correct, the Carina does not have lens covers which can be affected by sunlight, but rather they are a self contained bulb with a glass lens.

Comment: There may or may not be legal problems if you decide about swapping/retrofitting to a different illumination type. Unfortunately, I don't know if there are any and I have no idea if this is the proper place to ask that question.

Answer (score 2):

As I said previously, **[a set of Osram bulbs](http://www.osram.com/osram_com/news-and-knowledge/automotive-special/night-breaker-plus-limited-edition/index.jsp)** would help a lot. Further to that, your headlights may just need **[a nice polish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QwzHOO-3lk)**. Some people try to get real fancy with products and methods, but what it really comes down to is that you need to use various grades of sandpaper (from rough to very fine) and finish off with rubbing compound and/or liquid polish (I use Brasso, but any liquid polish should work).

Comment: If what I've seen is correct, the Carina does not have lens covers which can be affected by sunlight, but rather they are a self contained bulb with a glass lens.

Comment: You may still find that a good polish will remove the crap that sticks to your headlights.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth making sure that the bulbs are getting their full voltage - Halogen lamps drop off in brightness significantly as voltage drops.

Many cars of that age didn't have relayed headlamps, and so as the wiring has aged, it's resistance has increased, and the performance of the headlamps will suffer - fitting relays close to the lamps with new, good quality wiring can often help.

Comment: Very good point.

Comment: thanx! I will check with those points.

Comment: @Nick C , I decide to re-wire the all system with relays. I will add my result within few days....

Comment: Does wire really increase in resistance with age?  What mechanism would cause this?

Comment: As the wire gets older, it corrodes. This reduces the cross-section of the wire (as some of the copper has turned into copper oxide), and so increases the resistance (resistance being proportional to length divided by cross section) - put simply, the wire is smaller so less electrons can fit through it!